# express JS cors middleware does not work when server is accessed though fetch request

Tags: node.js, express, cors

Server is on http://localhost:3001, and client is same, but with port 3000.

On client I run simple fetch, I need to get logged-in user data from server, and currently I am doing it just using GET method(GET, POST, none work) like this(I also have to include cookies):

```
fetch("http://localhost:3001/user", {
      method: "GET",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

And the server:

```
const cors = require("cors");
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};
app.get("/user", cors(corsOptions), function(req, res, next) {
  u_session = req.session;
  const db_result = db
    .collection("users")
    .findOne({ email: u_session.email }, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;

      res.json({ email: result.email, type: result.type });
    });
});
```

What I get is cors error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/user' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Also if i go to server URL through browser, I can see access-allow-control-allow-origin header set successfully.

[image: sample]

Also as requested, screenshot of failed case network tab:
[image]

I've searched plenty of solutions on the internet, nothing seems to work. Am I missing something?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ive had this error while using Create react app and fetch before (likely not the same issue but could be a helpful analogy). The solution there was to set the proxy as the backend server url and remove the http://localhost:<port> from the fetch request. I did not haveto mess with any CORS options this way.

Comment: @MattPengelly Oh My Gosh, how many hours I have wasted on this, forgot that had proxy set up in client's packaje.json. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that if you have a proxy set that it is set to `http://localhost:3001`. After that adjust your `fetch` to only use a partial url like so:

```
fetch("/user", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

it should be safe to remove this as well:

```
const cors = require("cors");
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What sticks out to me is "preflight". I think it may be the `OPTIONS` request that doesn't have the correct CORS headers enabled. Ensure that you're enabling CORS on `GET`, `POST`, `OPTIONS`, and any other method your API supports.

Comment: None of the examples on official API documentation state need of this, and i am also not sure how to do this. What drives me crazy the most is, people use literally same code and same API as i do, and everything works for them without writing anything additional.

Comment: `cors` handles OPTIONS preflights automatically, as long as you supply the correct configuration options. It should not be necessary (and would be an undesireable pattern) to write your own OPTIONS endpoint alongside the OPTIONS processing `cors` already does in its handling of CORS requests,

Answer (score 0):

Since you send credentials from the client, you must configure your `cors` module to allow credentials via athe[`credentials` property](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuration-options). Also, `application/json` is a non-simple `Content-Type`, so you must allow that explicitly via `allowedHeaders`:

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type"]
};
```

Without this, the server will not include a `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header in the OPTIONS preflight, and the browser will refuse to send the main GET request.

Comment: @Nick You have to allow your non-simple `Content-type` as well. (Edited)

Comment: Would you have time to spare, if I uploaded this project files to github? (I know it becomes something like too much to ask, since we all are busy with stuff, dont want to be unnecessary burden) But from other side, that is literally the code, I dont know if it would make difference

Comment: @Nick What would be most helpful is if you could add the screenshots of the Network tabs for the *failing* case, so we could see the real-world request and response headers on the OPTIONS preflight.

Comment: Edited. I just noticed, it shows that "Provisional headers are shown" warning. Still don't know what causes it though, since i get this error in Edge too